# Can a gradle copy task be used to copy a file from a url?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Is it possible to copy a file from a http location using a gradle task

I tried something like this

```
task copyDatabaseFile(type: Copy) {
    from 'http://somelocation/somedatabasefile.cdl';
    into 'target location'
}
```

But that results in

```
Cannot convert URL 'http://server.cequint.com/cdldb/uscc/cityid.cdl' to a file.
```

I've not been able to find any gradle examples doing a similar thing

Comment: Do you need it to be a copy task? Because otherwise, you can always use a little bit of groovy to grab an online file

Comment: I'm not sure if it needs to be a task or not yet, I'm not yet sufficiently familiar with gradle to know. But the file needs to get copied before the actual build starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported by Gradle out of the box. But the VFS plugin should do the trick for you: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.ysb33r.vfs

Answer (score 1):

#### TextResource Service

You can use [TextResource](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.resources.TextResource.html) to download a file.

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts

val gradleReadme: TextResource = resources.text.fromUri(
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gradle/gradle/master/README.md"
)
```

A `TextResource` can be used as the input for a task. Here I've created a task that will download the file into the `src/main/resources/gradle_data` directory.

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts 
val gradleReadme: TextResource = resources.text.fromUri(
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gradle/gradle/master/README.md"
)

val downloadGradleReadme by tasks.registering(Sync::class) {
  from(gradleReadme) {
    rename { "README.json" }
  }
  into("src/main/resources/gradle_data")
}
```

I have to manually set the file name because the `TextResource` is not backed by a file.

#### Ant Get

It's easy to use the Ant "get" task in Gradle to download files.

Here's a Gradle (in Kotlin) that downloads the Gradle README.md into the the build directory. It also prints the status to console.

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts


val downloadGradleReadme by tasks.registering {
  val gradleReadmeUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gradle/gradle/master/README.md"

  inputs.property("gradleReadmeUrl", gradleReadmeUrl)

  val outputDir = temporaryDir
  outputs.dir(outputDir).withPropertyName("outputDir")

  doLast {

    val destinationFile = outputDir.resolve("readme.md")

    ant.withGroovyBuilder {
      "get"(
        "src" to gradleReadmeUrl,
        "dest" to destinationFile,
        "verbose" to true,
      )
    }

    logger.lifecycle("Downloaded Gradle README: ${destinationFile.readText()}")
  }
}
```

`ant.withGroovyBuilder(...)` runs immediately, so it's important to put it in the `doLast { ... }` block, so Gradle downloads the file during the *execution phase*, not the *configuration phase*.

The properties that can be used in the map can be found in the Ant [get task documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/get.html).

There's a few different ways of defining Ant tasks in Gradle. See [Using Ant from Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/ant.html) for more general information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use groovy to download and save a file from a url:

```
task downloadFile() << {
    def address='url/to/download.ext'
    def target='/path/tosave'

  new File("${address.tokenize('/')[-1]}").withOutputStream { out ->
      new URL(address).withInputStream { from ->  out << from; }
  }
}
```

If you need this task to always run (just) before build task is run, you could add to your build.gradle:

build.dependsOn downloadFile

Comment: I know this is a really old SO but isn't this more readable, you can obviously set the target dir as this does but it looks cleaner
def myUrl = new URL('url/to/download.ext')
new File("/path/tosave/${myUrl.file[myUrl.file.lastIndexOf('/')..<myUrl.file.length()]}") << myUrl.newInputStream()