# How can I execute curl in gradle and write a output file on specific directory?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Here is the code curl to download file in github private repo

```
def command = "curl -s -O https://myGitHubToken@raw.githubusercontent.com/myGitHubAccount/myrepo/master/app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml"
task myCurlTask(){
command.execute()
```

When I execute it the output file place in my root project directory.
I want to execute it and put the file in my res/values folder of my android project.

How can I do that?
And How to write that code in gradle.kts?

Comment: [You can use `TextResource` to download a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69823963/4161471)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found

```
tasks.register("downloadColorsFromPrivateRepo") {
val destinationPath = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/res/values/colors.xml"
val githubPrivateRepoToken = "myToken"
val command = "curl -o $destinationPath https://${githubPrivateRepoToken}@raw.githubusercontent.com/myGitHubAccount/myrepo/master/app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml"
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Gradle build files are written in a language called Groovy. You might consider looking for how to make an HTTP request and write the response to a file with this language directly rather than executing an external command.